# How do I configure iPhone in-app purchase between Game levels

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have not yet published my game to the app store.
I want to have it as free for initial X levels and in app purchase for (>X)  levels.
I read many docs about in-app purchase but somehow can't fit my game model for it.

I have this configuration for levels:

Start View -> Entry screen for Level N - startviewcontroller - user taps here to enter Level N.

Main View -> Play Scene for Level N - mainviewcontroller.

Once Level N is played, mainviewcontroller increments level no, and throws the user back to 
startviewcontroller with Level no N+1, and so on.

So I must place in-app purchase after main view, after user has played some level X.
And after user has purchased, it should lead the user to Start View - with level showing as 'Level X+1'.

Anyone has done such thing in past? 
I read somewhat about Storekit, and I want guidelines as to where should every bit of that code must go in my above design.

I will be highly grateful for any guidelines.

(As a side query: 
should I consider publishing it as in-app since very beginning, or should I just publish a free app first? 
What is easier? Getting in-app out or integrating it later on? Many thanks to anyone for helping out...)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852823/how-to-let-only-paid-members-into-my-ios-apps-some-sections-with-in-app-purchas

Comment: No, the post mentioned is quite different from what I need. Thanks for pointing though.